# Error: ENOENT: no such file or directory, open '/root/.ionic/daemon.log'

Tags: cordova, ionic-framework, npm

I had this error on windows 10, i did a fresh Ubuntu install over windows erasing everything, still...after i download newest nodejs version and newest ionic and cordova version i get this error when i try to use ionic..how?!?!?!?!

ionic info
[WARN] You are not in an Ionic project directory. Project context may be 
       missing.

cli packages: (/usr/lib/node_modules)

```
@ionic/cli-utils  : 1.12.0
ionic (Ionic CLI) : 3.12.0
```

System:

```
Node : v8.6.0
npm  : 5.3.0 
OS   : Linux 4.10
```

Answer (score 2):

I've faced the same issue as you, but I've done that steps and it worked.

1. Type `npm cache clean` and hit Enter.
2. Type `sudo npm install -g npm` and hit Enter.
3. Then type `npm install` and hit Enter. (you can ignore this step and run your project)

If you still have the same issue try `npm update` 
then run your ionic project.

here's the [link](https://github.com/visionmedia/debug/issues/261#issuecomment-207623445) of the steps

Comment: I gave up on windows, installed linux instead and now im not having any troubles

Comment: @DanielBezerraDeMenezes glad to help you anytime :)

Answer (score 0):

I had this issue when I was building the app inside a Docker container, it can also occur on any Ubuntu (or Linux) machine.

The error expects a **daemon.log** file that apparently does not exist. If you manually create the **daemon.log** file it should work without side-effects.

Just run the following commands:

```
mkdir -p /root/.ionic
touch /root/.ionic/daemon.log
```

After running these commands, all Ionic CLI commands should work correctly.